# Why is uglifier gem in default Rails Gemfile still of version 1.3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

When creating a new Rails 4 app the default `Gemfile` has this in the gem list:

```
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
```

This despite that [the last official version of uglifier being 2.4.0](http://rubygems.org/gems/uglifier)

Am I missing something here or why the discrepancy in versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundler version specifier `'>= 1.3.0'` means **at least** version 1.3.0 should be accepted. In other words, using the current version 2.4.0 is just fine.

In fact, that's the installed version you're going to have when starting a new application from scratch. Just check your `Gemfile.lock` file for the actual installed versions of gems in your bundle. You'll probably find something like this:

```
uglifier (2.4.0)
  execjs (>= 0.3.0)
  json (>= 1.8.0)
```

Which means you have uglifier 2.4.0.

More info: http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic_version_constraint